7zip в чем разница между архивами?

Эти архивы делают одной и той же программой, но почему то они выглядят по разному.

Включите отображение расширений - и вопрос сам собой отпадёт.

В Windows каждая программа может быть ассоциирована с определенными типами файлов. Например, архивы формата ZIP могут открываться как с помощью встроенного проводника Windows, так и с помощью 7-Zip. Каждая из этих программ может использовать свои собственные иконки для отображения файлов, что приводит к визуальным различиям.

